# What is the default size of Socket "Max Per Group" in Chrome, Mozilla and IE?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

How we can change max size of socket `Max Per Group`?

[image: Image where socket size should be changed]

I think this setting is done from registry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have tested recently,

> **Chrome** support max **6 connection** per host
>   **Firefox** support max **6 connection** per host
>   **IE v11** support max **8 connection** per host